# HTML5 video control with ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

How to control a video tag using C# in a ASP.NET project?
I have a list to interact with the page, and I want to be able to set the attributes of the video and then play it when the function is called.

In the page.aspx

```
<form id="form" runat="server">
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="radio" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="someFunction" AutoPostBack="True">
<asp:ListItem Selected="True">Item 1</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
</form>
```

In the page.aspx.cs

```
...
protected void someFunction(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    switch(radio.SelectedItem.Value)
    {
        ...
        case "Item 2":
            video.Attributes["src"] = "video.mp4";
            video.Attributes["type"] = "video/mp4";
            //Then I want to be able to play it
        break;
        ...
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Your question sort of reads as a set of requirements. Any code to show? What research have you done? These things will help us help you.  Good luck!

Comment: That's not the way the Internet works. You can't simply toggle play and pause from the server side. Request comes in -> server generates response -> server sends HTML, CSS and JavaScript to client via HTTP response. The server can't directly affect the client after it's sends the response. Why would you want to control a video from the server side anyways? Are you not familiar with client side scripting?

Comment: What ways do you want to control it?

Comment: Edited, sorry for the bad question formulation. I've done some research on Google, but I did not find a way to do it.

Comment: You are manipulating the HTML that you send down to the client, but you can't manipulate it directly after you've sent it to the client. That's not how it works. If you want to automatically play the video, you'll need to run some JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The autoplay attribute can achieve pretty much the same thing I wanted to do (Play the video when a item is selected).

```
<video id="video" runat="server" autoplay="autoplay"></video>
```